# Coordinate entry in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am frustrated by the seeming difficulty of calculating x,y coordinates in QGIS 3. As a longtime user of ArcGIS I find Esri much easier for this. However, I like QGIS and think in many ways it is more powerful. So, how does one easily enter x,y coordinates in a shapefile attribute table with QGIS 3, and furthermore be able to select units, e.g. decimal degree, lat/long, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

To calculate coordinates of features, open the `attribute table` of your layer and then the [`field calculator`](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html). Create a `new field` and make sure to choose the `correct field type` (E.g. float with precision 8). Enter `$x` for x-coordinates and `$y` to calculate the y-coordinate for each feature. **Units, by default are specified by the layers CRS.**

But of course you can transform them. You can use this universal expression for that:

`x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))` and

`y(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer_name, 'crs'), 'EPSG:4326'))`

This will transform x and y coordinates of any source CRS to WGS84 with unit degree. Just enter another EPSG-Code if you want a different one (e.g. to get units in meters, like UTM).

Using expressions in QGIS you can do almost everything you want to. So for example you can create a combined string field of x and y coordinates by using the concatenator `||`. E.g. `$x || ',' || $y`. Or create a WKT string and stuff like that.

Answer (score 4):

As your question is about overall QGIS 3, the answer by [MrXsquared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/107424/mrxsquared) is the best.

If you have access to QGIS 3.8 or later, try **Add X/Y fields to layer** (see visual changelog ["New Feature: Add X/Y fields to layer"](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog38/index.html#feature-add-x-y-fields-to-layer). It can be found in the `Processing Toolbox > Vector table`).

You can add X/Y fields calculated in the CRS of your choice.